# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'package_line_id' referenced before assignment (Python)

Tags: python, odoo-10

I'm trying to create a function def calculate_delivery_schedule that returns the value.

I don't think that's the issue in this case, This is my code;

Here is my .py  code=

```
def calculate_delivery_schedule(self):
    delivery_orders = {}
            utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
            have_delivery_schedule = False
            total_qty = 0
            for sale_order_line in self.order_line:
                if sale_order_line.schedule_line_ids:
                    if len(sale_order_line.schedule_line_ids) > 1:
                        have_delivery_schedule = True
                    else:
                        have_delivery_schedule = False
                    print "line 28", have_delivery_schedule, sale_order_line.schedule_line_ids, len(sale_order_line.schedule_line_ids)
                    for schedule in sale_order_line.schedule_line_ids:
                        if schedule.date2 not in delivery_orders:
                            if sale_order_line.product_id.pack:
                                delivery_list = {}
                                for package_line_id in sale_order_line.package_line_ids:
                                    val_q = package_line_id.qty * schedule.qty
                                    delivery_list.update(
                                        {
                                            package_line_id.product_id: val_q
                                        })
                                delivery_orders[schedule.date2] = delivery_list
                            else:
                                delivery_orders[schedule.date2] = {sale_order_line.product_id: schedule.qty}
                                print "line 41", delivery_orders[schedule.date2]
                        else:
                            if sale_order_line.product_id.pack:
                                for product_uom_qty in sale_order_line.package_line_ids:
                                    delivery_orders[schedule.date2].update({package_line_id.product_id: schedule.qty})
                            else:
                                delivery_orders[schedule.date2][sale_order_line.product_id] = schedule.qty
                        total_qty += schedule.qty
```

return with this have_delivery_schedule

```
if have_delivery_schedule:
                print "test", have_delivery_schedule
                print "do", delivery_orders
                for date2, vals_dict in delivery_orders.iteritems():
                    print "date2", date2
                    print "delivery_orders", delivery_orders
                    for prod_key, vals in vals_dict.iteritems():
                        print "Line 81", total_qty
                        print vals
                        delivery_orders[date2][prod_key] = vals / total_qty
                        # delivery_orders[date][product_qty] = total_qty
                        print "line 83 -------------------------------------", vals, total_qty, schedule.qty
                print "Line 84 : ", delivery_orders
        print "Line 86: ", delivery_orders
        return delivery_orders
        # else:
        #     return False
```

Error:

```
  File "/media/f/Data/odoo10/product_pack/models/sale_order.py", line 95, in action_confirm
    schedule_deliveries = self.calculate_delivery_schedule()
  File "/media/f/Data/odoo10/product_pack/models/sale_order.py", line 49, in calculate_delivery_schedule
    delivery_orders[schedule.date2].update({package_line_id.product_id: schedule.qty})
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'package_line_id' referenced before assignment
```

How to fix it? any ideas?

Comment: The error message is rather clear: The local variable was used before it was set.

Answer (score 0):

```
delivery_orders[schedule.date2].update({package_line_id.product_id: schedule.qty})
```

When you used package_line_id in the above line of code, you did not realise that it was never set in this else block but in its corresponding if block. So when the else executes, this variable has not been set. Hope this is clear.

Comment: I am not clear, should I define it in every other block? define package_line_id

Comment: Yes you need to. When you did 'for package_line_id in sale_order_line.package_line_ids' it was set for that block. So either set it earlier as a variable or here again. <br> Indenting in python is used to define scope and thats the limit of the variables declared there. Thats why you can reuse variables in other functions without conflicts (not advised always)